# Upload image and storing the filename in database WITH AJAX - [Doctrine 2- ZF2]

Tags: jquery, ajax, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 2 entities (post and images), fieldset and form (with a Controller).

Post:
    id
    title

Images
    id
    filename
    epigraph
    post_id

All in a form, but I want to save the (can be multiple) images as png file with AJAX, and when the file is saved, I want to show the thumbnail and a input text (an epigraph).

Then, when I want to upload to the database (submit form), save the filename in table.images.

**PostEntity**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection as Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="posts")
*/
class Posts
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=48) */
    protected $title;

    /**
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * @param string $title
    * @return Posts
    */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

**ImagesEntity**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="images")
*/
class Images
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string", length=255) */
    protected $filename;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\Entity\Posts", inversedBy="images")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
    protected $post_id;

    /**
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getId() 
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * @param Images $filename
    * @return string
    */
    public function setFilename($filename)
    {
        if (is_array($filename) && isset($filename['tmp_name'])) {
            $filename = $filename['tmp_name'];
        }
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    /**
    * @return string 
    */
    public function getFilename() 
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    /**
    * @param Images $post_id
    * @return integer
    */
    public function setPost_id(Posts $post_id = null)
    {
        $this->post_id = $post_id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getPost_id()
    {
        return $this->post_id;
    }
}
```

**ImagesFieldset**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Form;

use Admin\Entity\Images;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\Element;

class ImagesFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('image');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Admin\Entity\Images'))->setObject(new Imagenes());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'filename',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\File',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'epigraph',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'post_id',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        ));

    }
}
```

**PostsFieldset**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Form;

use Admin\Entity\Posts;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\Element;

class PostsFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('noticias');
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Admin\Entity\Posts'))->setObject(new Posts());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        ));

        $imagesFieldset = new \Admin\Form\ImagesFieldset($objectManager);
        $this->add(array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name'    => 'images',
            'options' => array(
                'count' => 1,
                'target_element' => $imagesFieldset
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

**PostsForm**

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Form;

use Admin\Entity\Posts;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class PostsForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('new_post');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, '\Admin\Entity\Posts'));

        $postsFieldset = new \Admin\Form\PostsFieldset($objectManager);
        $postsFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($postsFieldset);

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
            'name' => 'csrf',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                'id' => 'enviar',
            ),
        ));

        $this->setValidationGroup([
            'posts' => [
                'id',
                'title',
                'images' => [
                    'filename',
                    'post_id',
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**CreateAction**

```
public function crearAction()
{
    $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    $form = new \Admin\Form\NoticiasForm($objectManager);
    $posts= new \Admin\Entity\Posts();

    $form->bind($posts);
    if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        $formData = array_merge_recursive(
            $this->request->getPost()->toArray(),
            $this->request->getFiles()->toArray()
        );
        $form->setData($formData);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $objectManager->persist($noticia);
            $objectManager->flush();
            die;
        }
    }
    return new ViewModel([
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('posts', ['action' => 'create']));
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
$posts = $form->get('posts');
?>
<?php echo $this->formHidden($posts->get('id')); ?>
<?php echo $this->formRow($posts->get('title')); ?>
<?php echo $this->formCollection($posts->get('images')); ?>
<?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('submit')); ?>
```

I don't do this question by laziness to do all this work,
I'm taking concepts from everywhere but I've been trying to do this three months ago, this time specifically asked the idea I want to implement.
Thank you so much to help me.

Comment: Upload to the database (submit form)

Comment: Please don't add additional information to a question using comments.  If you need to refine your question, please click the edit button found at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Collect data, submit to server via ajax, server-side script reads contents of post and updates database. I see you've included a lot of php code, but none of it really seems that relevant. Where's the javascript that sends an ajax request?

Comment: I've removed that,
My idea is to send via ajax to another action to save the image.
But how I pick the file name and then, store it in the database

Comment: Either have the user supply the filename, or get it from the file that was uploaded? Then, store it in the database just like you would anything else? I fail to see what part of this process you are having trouble with. Unless, you just haven't done any of it and expect us to do it.

Comment: If I understand what you said, Get the name from the file that was uploaded (but I want to use RenameUpload, to randomize the filename, and I see that sometimes generate some type of "conflict":

[Posts] array
 title
 [imagenes] array
  [0]
   [filename]
     [name]
     [tmp_name] php00000.tmp
     [size]
  [1]
   [filename]
     [name]
     [tmp_name] myrandomize.myformat
     [size]